# Unable to add widgets to sidebars in custom theme

Tags: theme-development, widgets

I'm trying to add a footer area to wordpress so I can drop widgets and things there.  I see my footer area in the admin section, but if I add a text (or any other) widget and then save it, nothing shows up on the footer.  If I refresh the page, the widget that I dragged to the right in my footer area is no longer listed there.

I checked the network requests and there aren't any errors that I'm seeing.  Did I miss a step?

**footer.php** contains:

```
<?php
get_sidebar('footer_widget_area');
wp_footer();
?>
```

**functions.php** contains:

```
// Register widgetized areas
function theme_widgets_init() {
    // Area 1
  register_sidebar( array (
  'name' => 'Primary Widget Area',
  'id' => 'primary_widget_area',
  'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
  'after_widget' => "</li>",
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
  ) );

    // Area 2
  register_sidebar( array (
  'name' => 'Secondary Widget Area',
  'id' => 'secondary_widget_area', 
  'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
  'after_widget' => "</li>",
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
  ) );

    // Footer
  register_sidebar( array (
  'name' => 'Footer',
  'id' => 'footer_widget_area', 
  'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
  'after_widget' => "</li>",
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
  ) );
} // end theme_widgets_init

add_action( 'init', 'theme_widgets_init' );
```

**Update:** It's not just the new widget area I can't add widgets to, it's all of them.

Comment: have you checked for javascript errors in console?

Comment: @Milo Yes, unfortunately there's nothing there either.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `get_sidebar` incorrectly. That function ["Includes the sidebar.php template file from your current theme's directory."](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar) And if you include a parameter, it loads a file matching that parameter name, not a sidebar of that name.

> If a name ($name) is specified then a specialized sidebar
>   sidebar-{name}.php will be included.

What you want is [`dynamic_sidebar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar) instead.

```
dynamic_sidebar('footer_widget_area');
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for pointing that out... though it didn't solve the issue on the admin side.

Comment: I can't duplicate that admin side error. Using the code in my answer plus your code, things work fine for me.

Comment: Try your code with all plugins disabled, and using a default theme. You'll have to edit the theme to test it but it should be OK since this is temporary debugging and can be overwritten on update.

Comment: It works with the default theme, doesn't work with mine.  I'll dig through their theme and see if any of their code is different...

Comment: Everything I've done is consistent with the 2012 theme.  Any other ideas on what could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think that using dynamic_sidebar you should actually be calling the index-order. Since dynamic_sidebar is supposed to be this:

```
dynamic_sidebar( $index );
```

So if you have 3 sidebars, then it should be:

```
dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-3' );
```

Comment: `$index` is `name` or `ID` field of the registered sidebar, not position.